# django staticfiles collection error

Tags: python, django

I started a new project in django and created a development and a testing environment with their settings in the same folder as the custom settings.py everything is going well till I created a static file directory and I tried to collect static files but got error.
`raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

this is my directory

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
if DEBUG:
        MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
        STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
        MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
        STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
    )
```

**test_settings.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from .settings import *

    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG


    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': '',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DEBUG = True` somewhere?

Comment: yes. in both `test_settings.py` and `development_settings.py`

Comment: wait, how do you know that `test_settings` is the one that's actually being used? Open a shell (`./manage.py shell') and print the settings.

Comment: I run each virtualenv in seprate shell tabs on my mac

Comment: I mean can you check in your shell that `STATIC_ROOT` is actually what you expect it to be?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: shell response `none`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157227/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-king).

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` should be an absolute filesystem path:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static-only'))
```

Also, I would recommend keeping your `STATICFILES_DIRS` to directories inside your `BASE_DIR` (as part of your project/repository) rather than outside.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove/comment `STATICFILES_DIRS` when running the `./manage.py collectstatic`, and change `STATIC_ROOT` to `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/static-only')`

Comment: no, you shouldn't have to comment out things when running collectstatic.